# Log/Print in child window

Tags: c, shell, logging, printing

I have a program that print me tons of datas. Those datas can be separated in 2 main topics : `infos log (ex : init, error, warning …)`  and `values (ex : density = 0,06 power = 12 …)`. Everything is refreshed every seconds and has become not readable at all (too many `infos`). I would like to clean everything.

What I would like to do is, when I launch my program, it opens automatically another shell window where this window only displays my values. So I have my main window where I launch the C program that prints the `infos` log and, this main, launches another window where it only prints my values.

Unfortunately I have no idea if it is possible and if so, where to look for. So here I am.
Probably looking for a way to “fold” my `printf`in category (using something like `Zlog`, but If you have something more suitable to me I’m okay) and a way to open a new child window where it only displays all my `“printf with id=values”`.

If i can explain in Pseudo-code

```
*Main {
-   Open child window
-   Do main calculation
- Printf all printf-id-datas
}
Child window fct{
-   Printf all printf-id-value
}
Logger {
 - Log all kind of printf
}*
```

Thank you for your help.
Do not hesitate if it’s not clear. Thank you.

Comment: No idea why you would want this. Why not write the data to a file? Then you can examine any way you may require.

Answer (score 0):

you can use stdout for data and stderr for logging.
then you can run your app and observe data in main console window

```
Main 2>logs.txt
```

and in other console you can look at logs:

```
tail -f logs.txt
```